# Convert Unix Epoch Time to MSZ date and time

Tags: unix, timezone, timestamp, abap

Does anyone of you have suggestions how to convert the Unix timestamp to ABAP MEZ/MESZ time and date?

The following code is from the ABAP-Reference, the code is for timestamps with lenght 15 or 21 but the Unix timestamp is currently 10 digits long.

```
    DATA: time_stamp TYPE timestamp,
      tz         TYPE ttzz-tzone.

tz = 'MESZ'.
time_stamp = 15319830890000.
CONVERT TIME STAMP time_stamp TIME ZONE tz
        INTO DATE DATA(dat) TIME DATA(tim)
        DAYLIGHT SAVING TIME DATA(dst).
cl_demo_output=>write( |{ dat DATE = ISO } {
                          tim TIME = ISO } { dst }| ).

time_stamp = 15319830890000.
CONVERT TIME STAMP time_stamp TIME ZONE tz
        INTO DATE dat TIME tim
        DAYLIGHT SAVING TIME dst.
cl_demo_output=>write( |{ dat DATE = ISO } {
                          tim TIME = ISO } { dst }| ).

cl_demo_output=>display( ).
```

Comment: It seems the demo code you posted uses a UNIX timestamp (seconds since the epoch / Jan 1 1970) - multiplied by a factor of 10^4. So maybe just try the same?

Comment: I don't know abap, but if supported you should use a standard [IANA time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) for a zone that references a region, such that you don't have to think about dst yourself.  In your case, I recommend `Europe/Berlin` instead of `MEZ` or `MESZ`.

Comment: MEZ and MESZ time zones are not delivered with an ABAP system, as you can see by starting the transaction STZBC.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with this code. I am using now 13 digits epoche...

```
    data: i(20) type n.

data: d type sy-datum."
data: t type sy-uzeit.
data: epoche type int8.
data: test type int8.
data: test2 type int8.

epoche = 1522836000000.

i = epoche / 1000.
d = '19700101'.
d = d + i div 86400.
t = i mod 86400.

write: d, t.
```

Comment: Here you can divide by 1000, but in your original post your example was 15319830890000 which had to be divided by 10000 (10^4, as @David Collins said)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert using a SAP time zone, this one can work too (no time to convert it to ABAP Objects):

```
FORM unixtime_2_date_time
      USING
        i_unixtime    TYPE numeric
        i_timezone    TYPE timezone
      CHANGING
        e_date        TYPE d
        e_time        TYPE t.

  DATA l_tstmp_unix_era TYPE TZNTSTMPL.
  DATA l_tstmp TYPE TZNTSTMPL.
  CONSTANTS utc TYPE timezone value IS INITIAL.

  CONVERT DATE '19700101' TIME '000000' INTO TIME STAMP l_tstmp_unix_era TIME ZONE utc.
  l_tstmp = CL_ABAP_TSTMP=>add( tstmp = l_tstmp_unix_era secs = i_unixtime ).
  CONVERT TIME STAMP l_tstmp TIME ZONE i_TIMEZONE INTO DATE e_date TIME e_time .
ENDFORM.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cl_pco_utility` Java utility class for that, particularly method **convert_java_timestamp_to_abap**. It perfectly accepts 10-character Unix time.

```
CLASS zcl_epoch DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS:
      unix_time_to_timestamp
        IMPORTING iv_timestamp TYPE timestamp.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS zcl_epoch IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD unix_time_to_timestamp.
    CONSTANTS: c_tzone TYPE ttzz-tzone VALUE 'CET'.
    DATA: lv_timestamp_msec TYPE string,
          lv_timestamp      TYPE timestamp,
          lv_date           TYPE datum,
          lv_time           TYPE uzeit.

    lv_timestamp_msec = iv_timestamp * 1000.
    cl_pco_utility=>convert_java_timestamp_to_abap(
      EXPORTING
        iv_timestamp = lv_timestamp_msec
      IMPORTING
        ev_date      = lv_date
        ev_time      = lv_time
    ).

    lv_timestamp = lv_date && lv_time.
    CONVERT TIME STAMP lv_timestamp TIME ZONE c_tzone INTO DATE lv_date TIME lv_time.

    cl_demo_output=>display( |{ lv_date DATE = ISO } { lv_time TIME = ISO }| ).
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  zcl_epoch=>unix_time_to_timestamp( '1532196799' ).
```

It worth mentioning that MEZ/MSEZ are **NOT** standard abbreviations and should not be used. For example, MEZ is the same as CET. Look at list of common time zones [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations) or [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/).

Also, it's better to stick to list of available time zones of your system, which is table TTZZ.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the epoch time to '19700101' date with initial time.

```
DATA lv_initial_timestamp TYPE timestamp.

CONVERT DATE '19700101' TIME '000000' INTO TIME STAMP lv_initial_timestamp TIME ZONE sy-zonlo.

ev_timestamp = cl_abap_tstmp=>add( tstmp = lv_initial_timestamp secs = iv_epoch_timestamp ).

CONVERT TIME STAMP ev_timestamp TIME ZONE sy-zonlo INTO DATE ev_date TIME ev_time.
```

For MEZ/MESZ you can choose time zone accordingly.